# SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print', while trying to run system

Tags: bash, scripts, syntax

I am trying to run my system *(Empire PowerShell),* but it keeps giving me a syntax error. The system I used didn't support python3, so I had to install python2 which ended up working. But when I try to run it by `./empire` it instead gives me a syntax error stating,

```
print '[*] Fresh start in docker, running reset.sh for you' SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
```

I tried to look up if anyone else had this problem with it, but I didn't find it. I gave myself permission so I can access and look at the Dockerfile but I couldn't seem to figure it out. It also states:

```
File "/root/Empire/./empire" Line 35
```

It may be a connection to the Dockerfile but I will state what the Dockerfile says if it does in fact involve it most likely. The Dockerfile also has numbered lines like *"Line 34"* etc, but no Line 35.

Comment: Python 2 and 3 have different syntax, like parentheses on the print command.  Try to install python3.

Comment: I do have python3 installed but it kept giving me an error with using python 3 for my system that I want to run, so I had to install python 2 so it can work with it. But instead, it gives me this error, unless I need to downgrade my Ubuntu to work with python2? But the version of Ubuntu was supposed do okay with python2 I heard unless that's wrong.

Comment: When installing another Python, do not try to override the system default --  that is a sure way to break your system.  Use the additional Python exclusively for the project that needs it. First thing is to figure out what's the system default, and what your project needs.